# what happend in javascript source after appended td,tr of table

Tags: javascript

1.I run this codes.

```
<table id="widgetTable" class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>NO.</th>
</tr></thead> </table>

//skip details

$("#widgetTable > tbody:last").append('<tr><td>'+ (i+1) +'</td></tr>);
//upper code line is succeesed in run time
```

2. But be appended td isnt find in table when using debugging tools of browser (be unchanged source)
3. so bottom codes wasnt activited? how can i do! tell me a way.. :(

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#widetTable').find('tr').click( function(){

   var selected = $(this).hasClass("highlight");
      $("#widetTable tr").removeClass("highlight");
      if(!selected)
              $(this).addClass("highlight");
   
    alert('You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error on the line `$("#widgetTable > tbody:last").append('<tr><td>'+ (i+1) +'</td></tr>);` in your first code block - missing closing `'` before the last `)`. What debugging tools are you using? If you just use the "View Page Source" option it is supposed to show you the *original* source from before it was modified by JS.

Comment: Read about [__`Event delegation`__](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: @nnnnnn  oh I'm sorry that my mistake. the original source diffrent it(no matter source) . I used dev-tool of chrome. how I can see that is changed source???

Comment: In Chrome, press F12 to open the dev tools, and then look at the "Elements" tab. That shows the current DOM.

Comment: ?? ah until i dont know between elements and sources tab. anyway. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically generated elements, you want to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method. 
So this:

```
$('#widetTable').find('tr').click( function(){
```

Would become:

```
$('#widetTable').on( 'click', 'tr', function() {
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878976/1409180)

> I would prefer .on over .click because the former can use less memory and work for dynamically added elements.

Comment: `.on('click', function() {` does exactly the same thing as `.click(function() {`.

Comment: Nope. How about you read the jQuery doco for `.on()`. The behaviour of the `.on()` method changes depending on what arguments you call it with: for it to work with dynamically added elements you have to supply a selector as the second argument to `.on()`. It's not a direct replacement for `.live()`.

Comment: You're right about the second argument that I missed. I've updated that above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to attach a click event on tr elements of the table where the tr are dynamically added. If so.., then try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#widetTable').on("click", "tr", function(event){

         var selected = $(this).hasClass("highlight");
            $("#widetTable tr").removeClass("highlight");
            if(!selected)
                    $(this).addClass("highlight");

          alert('You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
        });
});
```

Comment: am sorry i cant write english well :( .....  anyway. nothing happens though fix my source

Comment: can you provide a jsFiddle link, to debug